# NoTargetForURIException While deploying application on Websphere with IntelliJ

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, deployment, websphere

i tried many times to deploy my jee application using intelliJ on Websphere 8.5 the compilation goes well untill i get this error on browser :

```
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /RootServlet
```

everything is well configured on web.xml, welcomefile - servlet name - and servlet mapping

Is there anyone who can help me with this issue ?

Ps : i'm using websphere 8.5.5.11 Developer

Comment: Even though you think "everything is configured well", the app server doesn't seem to think so.  If you post your web.xml, someone may spot an issue....

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out: `localhost:8080/myappname_war_exploded`, and in my `application.xml` in my WAR I had `myappname`, so just deleting the `_war_exploded` resolved the issue.